# Oracle query to join two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master list table with following field

Table A

1. columnname (used as column name in transaction table  values like A, B, C)
2. item no ( used as value for that column, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2)
3. item_description used to display on screen

Table B

1. Id
2. A (name from Table A and storing item_no as Value)
3. B
4. C

now I have to fetch Itemdescription from Table A for a Corresponding value in Table B.

Comment: Is this something other than a join?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT b.item_description
  FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b on ( a.item_no = b.A );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have over-obfuscated your sample data which makes it hard to understand the use case but I think you have a mix of metadata and real data in table `A`. Which is horrible. I'm sure the originator of this design had reasons but the outcome is always horrible queries.

Here is one solution, which is arguably less horrible than the alternatives.

```
select b.id
       , t_a.Itemdescription as a_Itemdescription
       , t_b.Itemdescription as b_Itemdescription
       , t_c.Itemdescription as c_Itemdescription
from b
     left outer join 
          ( select a.itemdescription
                   , a.item_no
            from a
            where a.columnname = 'A') t_a
           on t_a.item_no b.a
     left outer join 
          ( select a.itemdescription
                   , a.item_no
            from a
            where a.columnname = 'B') t_b
           on t_b.item_no b.b
     left outer join 
          ( select a.itemdescription
                   , a.item_no
            from a
            where a.columnname = 'C') t_c
           on t_c.item_no b.c
```

---

To be honest I'm not sure this is the answer you're looking for. If it isn't please **edit your question** to clarify the requirement. It is a good idea to provide sample data as rows in tables and to post example output which is derived from the input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select a.*, b.description
from a join
     b
     on (a.columnname = 'A' and a.itemno = b.A) or
        (a.columnname = 'B' and a.itemno = b.B) or
        (a.columnname = 'C' and a.itemno = b.C);
```

In Oracle, you can shorten this to:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on (a.columnname, a.itemno) in ( ('A', A), ('B', B), ('C', C));
```

This may not be particularly efficient.  So a more efficient method is:

```
select a.*, coalesce(ba.description, bb.description, bc.description)
from a left join
     b ba
     on a.columnname = 'A' and a.itemno = ba.A left join
     b bb
     on a.columnname = 'B' and a.itemno = bb.B left join
     b bc
     on a.columnname = 'C' and a.itemno = bc.C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Left Join  to work through the query